# error function declared but never defined

Tags: c, avr, codevisionavr

I have added a library to my c project in codeVision AVR. when I want to use it's functions receive this error:
function 'function name' is declared but never defined.
here is my code:

```
#include "pid.h"
#include <mega32.h>
PidType _pid;
void main(void)
{
//some uC hardware initializing codes which are removed here to simplify code
PID_Compute(&_pid);
while (1)
  {
  // Place your code here

  }
}
```

in pid.h:

```
.
.
bool PID_Compute(PidType* pid);
.
.
```

and pid.c:

```
#include "pid.h"
.
.
bool PID_Compute(PidType* pid) {
  if (!pid->inAuto) {
    return false;
  }
    FloatType input = pid->myInput;
    FloatType error = pid->mySetpoint - input;
    pid->ITerm += (pid->ki * error);
    if (pid->ITerm > pid->outMax)
      pid->ITerm = pid->outMax;
    else if (pid->ITerm < pid->outMin)
      pid->ITerm = pid->outMin;
    FloatType dInput = (input - pid->lastInput);

    FloatType output = pid->kp * error + pid->ITerm - pid->kd * dInput;

    if (output > pid->outMax)
      output = pid->outMax;
    else if (output < pid->outMin)
      output = pid->outMin;
    pid->myOutput = output;


    pid->lastInput = input;
    return true;
}
```

the ERROR:

function 'PID_Compute' declared, but never defined.

Where is the problem?

EDIT:

to add the library to my project I placed the .c and .h library files in the same folder that my main project file is:

[image]

and then #include "pid.h" in my main file:

```
#include "pid.h"
#include <mega32.h>

// Declare your global variables here
PidType _pid;
void main(void)
{
.
.
```

my error and warnings:
[image]

[image]

[image]

EDIT2:
I simplified the code and now can show you the entire code:
main code:

```
#include "pid.h"
PidType _pid;
void main(void)
{
PID_Compute(&_pid);
while (1)
      {

      }
}
```

pid.h:

```
#ifndef PID_H
#define PID_H

#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct {
 int i;
} PidType;


bool PID_Compute(PidType* pid);

#endif
```

pid.c:

```
#include "pid.h"
bool PID_Compute(PidType* pid) {

    pid->i = 2;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: looks like `pid.c` is not being linked with your main program. Probably you did not add it properly to your project

Comment: Post the build log in its entirety (following a rebuild-all / clean rebuild).  It should show you what is being compiled and what is being linked. Both pid.c and whatever file `main()` is in must be compiled then their respective object files linked.  Clearly pid.c is not included.  You say you have added it to your project but did not say how you did that.  BTW this is not strictly a "library", it is simply a _module_ or _translation unit_; if you added it to the project as a _library_, that might be the problem.

Comment: A "declared but not defined" error usually means you've declared a static function in a file but never actually defined the function.  It usually isn't a linker error.  The linker error would normally be 'undefined reference'.  You need to show us an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name
Your code is sub-minimal; we cannot compile it to reproduce the error you see.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I put a MCVE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you every body.
As you said, the pid.c was not added to the project.
for those who may face the same problem:
in codeVision AVR we have to add .c file to project from project->configure->files->input files->add

I addec .c file to project and the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot with the tree view of your files it is clear that the file "pid.c" is not part of the project.

Move it into your project. Then it should build without that linker error.

This does not mean the location in the file system. I reference the "virtual" view of the IDE on your project.

Comment: "pid.c" is in the same place that "pid.h" is.